# Distorting a layer to fit shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have a rectangular image which I'd like to distort so that it fits into a shape. I can almost do it using "Distort", but I need to move more than just the corners, which is all I can seem to do using distort. The midpoints just scale along that direction.

This is approximatly what I want to achieve:
[image: What I want]

There'd probably be more distortion, but I painted this by hand... I can use either Photoshop or Illustrator, if either one is more suited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is easily achieved in Illustrator using Envelope Distort:

1. Draw your pattern/shape/whatever to be warped

   [image: Pattern to warp]
2. Draw the shape to guide the warping

   [image: Guide shape]
3. Select both object (with guide shape on top) and use `Tools` ⇒ `Envelope Distort` ⇒ `Make With Top Object` (keyboard shortcut Alt + Ctrl + C)

   [image: Warped!]

The default options may make the edges too smooth for your taste.  Check `Object` ⇒ `Envelope Distort` ⇒ `Envelope Options`.  Higher fidelity = sharper corners.

You can do a lot o' cool stuff with Envelope Distort...
[image: GD Flag]

Comment: No question about it. The PS distort would be a nightmare for this. (You could get there using Vanishing Point, I think, but it would be tricky, not to mention tedious.)